# Flutter: Error: Getter not found: 'suspending'. case AppLifecycleState.suspending

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, dependencies, flutter-dependencies

I just upgraded Flutter on Stable Channel and got the following StackTrace, when trying to launch an App (on local iOS Simulator). Running unit-tests with `flutter test` are also affected.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode...

Compiler message:
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/native_device_orientation-0.1.2/lib/native_device_orientation.dart:149:30: Error: Getter not found: 'suspending'.
      case AppLifecycleState.suspending:
                             ^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
Failed to build bundle.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
```

Flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G1012, locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (33 hours ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0-rc2)
    • Android SDK at ...Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.0-rc2
    • Java binary at: .../bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3, Build version 11C29
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 8 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

Anybody got a solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue.

Please have a look at the changelog of the native_device_orientation package:

"Breaking change to support the fact that AppLifecycleState.suspended has changed to AppLifecycleState.detached."

One of your packages may depends on this library. Here you can find a list of the packages https://pub.dev/packages?q=dependency%3Anative_device_orientation.

For me it was qr_mobile_vision.

Comment: I'm not using any of those packages you linked but still getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, found the cause and submitted a new answer.

Answer (score 6):

To make the answer slightly more broader in scope than the one already submitted by @x23b5, it is indeed caused by this [PR](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/11913) into the flutter master channel on Nov 4th.

The PR updated the enum: `AppLifecycleState.suspending` to `AppLifecycleState.detached`.

You may be using a dependency in one of your plugins that relies on this enum such as [one of these](https://pub.dev/packages?q=dependency%3Anative_device_orientation) - in which case your debug error message will point you towards that plugin - then simply visit its github repo and see if the author has issued a patch. If not, feel free to edit that single line and submit a PR for them.

If on the other hand you've manually written code (like my case) that leveraged AppLifecycleState, search your code for it and manually update suspending to detached and restart flutter.

Comment: you saved my time, I exhausted by this issue.

Comment: I have hundreds of dependancies; what should I do?

Comment: Grep your codebase and dependency folder for `AppLifecycleState.suspending`.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same issue. Updated qr_mobile_vision to version 0.3.1 seems to have resolve the problem.